# Ruby on Rails Drop Down Box not committing to database (Model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, drop-down-menu

I have a rails form to collect information on people for a family tree application. There are two drop down boxes that are used to assign the parents of the person being edited/created, however when a selection is made in either, or both, of these boxes, it is not committed to the database. It doesn't throw any exceptions, however when I check the database, the fatherID and motherID fields remain as null.

Here is the complete code for the form:

Does anybody have any ideas where I'm going astray?
Thanks.

```
<%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
  <% if @person.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@person.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this person from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :FirstName %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :FirstName %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :LastName %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :LastName %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :MaidenName %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :MaidenName %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Sex %><br>

    <%= f.select(:Sex, options_for_select([['Male', 'M'], ['Female', 'F']]))%>
  </div>
    <div class="field"> 
<p>Parents:</p>

   Mother: <%= select(:motherID, options_from_collection_for_select(Person.all, :id, :FirstName), :include_blank => true)%>

   Father: <%= select(:fatherID, options_from_collection_for_select(Person.all, :id, :FirstName), :include_blank => true)%>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller code

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /people
  # GET /people.json
  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  # GET /people/1
  # GET /people/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /people/new
  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  # GET /people/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /people
  # POST /people.json
  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /people/1
  # PATCH/PUT /people/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.update(person_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /people/1
  # DELETE /people/1.json
  def destroy
    @person.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to people_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_person
      @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:FirstName, :LastName, :MaidenName, :Sex)
    end
end
```

Model Code

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
end
```

Comment: part of code in your action when your form is submitted? and some log data?

Comment: motherID database field should be snake case first. second can you put your controller code and model here. also motherID and fatherID are not in person hash so they are not included when updating the database

Comment: Please share you controller and model code.

Comment: @NitinJ Does snake case make a difference in rails? I'm new to this so apologies if this is an obvious question! I'll look into the hash now.

Comment: yes lets say if you have a model name User and Person now User has_many :persons and Person belongs_to :user now persons table has a field with name user_id . Because rails follow this convention t. though you can override that in your model by telling foreign key explicitly. let me know if it helps you and one more thing you have to allow that param  for strong parameter to be accessible n model for updating that.

Comment: also make little change <%= f.select(:motherID, options_from_collection_for_select(Person.all, :id, :FirstName), :include_blank => true)%>

   Father: <%= f.select(:fatherID, options_from_collection_for_select(Person.all, :id, :FirstName), :include_blank => true)%>

Comment: Thanks - I've got it fixed now - I'm going to go and re factor the motherID and fatherID!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:motherID` and `:fatherID` need to be in `params.require(:person).permit(:FirstName, :LastName, :MaidenName, :Sex)` otherwise the controller does not pass these values to the model for them to be saved.

For more information about strong parameters, see the rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be something relatively straightforward like that. I would up vote your answer but I don't have enough reputation, if someone else would be so kind it would be appreciated!